# SQL Server 2014 returns deadlock (error 1205) when run simultaneously more than 60 updating processes on the same DB table

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, deadlock

I have a database in SQL Server 2014.

I run a test that checks simultaneous update scenario on the same table (X rows)
The test creates X threads and they call my function `UpdateDB()`. Each thread updates only its one row (thread per row) every 30 sec. So there no place for a scenario when 2 threads update at the same time the same row.

When I run this test with X=59 (rows=threads=59) - everything is ok. Once I increased to 60 rows\threads - I start getting:

> "Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."

I have deadlock graph if you need. But firstly I need to understand may be there limitations setting in SQL Server that I need to change\increase? any other ideas why specifically number of simultaneous updates causes deadlock?

Thanks!

```
UpdateDB(int rowId)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringDB))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand DBCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            string SQLCommand = string.Empty;

            SQLCommand = "UPDATE MyTable SET result = @myResult WHERE ExecutionID = @exID AND RowId = @rowId";

            DBCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exID", CurrentExecutionId);
            DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowId", rowId);
            DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myResult", "OK");

            DBCommand.CommandText = SQLCommand;
            DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            //here I get 1205
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: You might want to post the table structure. Locking can occur on the table, page, row, indexes, etc.

Comment: We can suggest trying locking hints like `UPDATE MyTable WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK) SET [...]` but without knowing the table and index structure and deadlock information its going to be impossible to tell what's going on.  [Lock escalation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) does occur when the server is under heavier loads, however.

Comment: I don't see how that statement could deadlock at all. Perhaps I'm missing something, but shouldn't a single statement in a implicit transaction just "queue up" if it's blocked, assuming that it still gets to execute within the normal query timeout?

Comment: @BaconBits and others. Sorry for delay in asnwer. I'm not sure what you mean as "table structure". PSB:  Checked\Uncheked it is "Allow Nulls": ExecutionID int Unchecked;
RowId int Unchecked
Result varchar(MAX) Checked

Answer (score 0):

You could be hitting a lock escalation threshold, although it is very strange that it is always from 59 to 60 threads. For details see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx

Another thing you could look at is your code that the problem comes at 60 when there is a call per 30 sec per thread. Is it related to 2 calls per second?